# What are the helicopter frequencies on the LA heli charts used for?

Tags: air-traffic-control, rotorcraft

The LA heli charts list frequencies for the different heli routes in LA:
[image]

Are the frequencies used as a "CTAF" for helicopters, or is there an air traffic controller on that frequency telling helicopters what to do? I'm also wondering if the helicopter freq 119.80 at LAX issues class bravo transitions?

Answer (score 1):

This is the frequency for the tower controller who is due to control inbound helicopters. You can see LAX 119.8, HHR 121.1 and LGB 120.5 frequencies noted. These are all frequencies used by the tower controller at these aerodromes.

At LAX, the class bravo transition will be issued by the tower controller on 119.8.

Comment: Thanks. If we're talking to Hawthorne on their helicopter frequency, would we ring up "Hawthorne Tower" or "Hawthorne Helicopters"? Also, is the bravo transition on 119.8 only for helicopter shoreline routes, or do mini route transitions also use 119.8?

Comment: Hawthorne Tower is the callsign of the position working you. 119.8 Should be for anyone looking to transition the bravo.